# Issue mocking a Python module global variable assignment

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

This is the module under test

**ecr.py**

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ecr')


def get_tags(repository):
    response = client.list_images(repositoryName=repository)
    tags = [image['imageTag'] for image in response['imageIds']]
    return tags
```

This is the test

**ecr_test.py**

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock

from mirror import ecr_service
from tests import fake_requests

class TestEcrService(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_tags(self):
        with mock.patch('boto3.client', fake_requests.fake_client):
            tags = ecr_service.get_tags('prometheus')
        self.assertEqual(['v2.33.4', 'v2.33.3'], tags)
```

The mocked function from code above only works if I move boto3.client to inside the funtion, like so.

**ecr.py**

```
import boto3


def get_tags(repository):
    response = boto3.client('ecr').list_images(repositoryName=repository)
    tags = [image['imageTag'] for image in response['imageIds']]
    return tags
```

What's the correct way for mocking boto3.client in the global scope?

---

I solved this by removing the variable from the global scope. This is the final version:

**ecr.py**

```
import boto3


def get_tags(repository):
    response = boto3.client('ecr').list_images(repositoryName=repository)
    tags = [image['imageTag'] for image in response['imageIds']]
    return tags
```

**ecr_test.py**

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

from mirror import ecr_service
from tests import fake_requests


class TestEcrService(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_tags(self):
        with mock.patch('boto3.client', fake_requests.fake_client):
            tags = ecr_service.get_tags('prometheus')
        self.assertEqual(['v2.33.4', 'v2.33.3'], tags)
```

Comment: You have to patch where the object is uses, in `ecr.py`: `mock.patch('ecr.client')`

Comment: If I mock ecr.client, boto3.client will be called with the real function and I want to prevent that, so I want to mock boto3.client. This does not work either ```with mock.patch('mirror.ecr_service.boto3.client', fake_requests.fake_client):```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this as I have a similar issue, where I cannot mock the object because at the point my module is loaded a call is made to AWS before boto3 is mocked causing my test to fail before it even runs.

Comment: @berimbolo I've updated the thread with the final solution.

Comment: @AndreFagundes thanks, I also did the same last week because I couldn't find a solution, its good to see we arrived at the same solution though as I felt I was copping out a little by doing this. Cheers!